# Access Main Form from Subclass

Tags: c#, winforms

For my C# program I create the below object.

```
processurls processurls1 = new processurls();
```

After I create it I click a button to start my timer which executes:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    processurls1.pURLS(UrlList, URLCountOf, HTTP, label1, TotalURLS2, TotalURLS);
}
```

This timer every 500milliseconds will trigger the pURLS function of my processurls1 object. 
It will update my main forms Label label1.text everytime.
But my problem is it will only update the label once and my program runs extremely clunky. What is a safe way to pass label objects & picturebox objects to my subclass to be updated properly on the main form without lag?

```
public void pURLS(List<string> UrlListOf, int Count, Images HTTP, Label label1, int TotalURLS2, int TotalURLS)
{
    try
    {
        string WebResponse = HTTP.DoGET(UrlListOf[Count]);
        string pattern = "href=\"(.*?)\"";
        MatchCollection OtherURLS = Regex.Matches(WebResponse, pattern);
        for (int i = 0; i < OtherURLS.Count; i++)
        {

            Match HasHttp = Regex.Match(OtherURLS[i].Value, "http");
            if (HasHttp.Success)
            {
                string CleanedUp = Regex.Replace(OtherURLS[i].Value, "href=\"", "");
                CleanedUp = Regex.Replace(CleanedUp, "\"", "");

                UrlListOf.Add(CleanedUp);
                TotalURLS2++;
            }
            else
            {
                string CleanedUp = Regex.Replace(OtherURLS[i].Value, "href=\"", "");
                CleanedUp = Regex.Replace(CleanedUp, "\"", "");
                CleanedUp = UrlListOf[TotalURLS2] + "" + CleanedUp;
                UrlListOf.Add(CleanedUp);
                TotalURLS2++;
            }
        }

        label1.Text = "U:" + TotalURLS2.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is to get rid of this all-exception-eating `catch` block to see any errors that actually might happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn async basis.

Perhaps 500 ms is not enough to fetch/data. Instead of using timer, just use an async Task with a xx ms sleep

On your  MainForm

```
public async Task UpdateMyLabels()
{
  while (true) //change here by something more reliant
  {
       await processurls1.pURLS(UrlList, URLCountOf, HTTP, label1, TotalURLS2, TotalURLS);
       Thread.Sleep(200); //ajust value here
  }
}
```

On your "form loaded" event :

```
{
       UpdateMyLabels();
}
```

Finally, add the "async" keyword on pUrls :

```
public async Task pURLS
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all my variables into the class itself. Now I can access a property from my backgroundworker and update the main form :D

```
    static int ImageCount = 0;
    static int currentImage = 0;
    Images HTTP = new Images();
    List<string> UrlList;
    static List<string> ImageCollection = new List<string>();

    public List<string> Images
    {
        get
        {
            return ImageCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            ImageCollection = value;
        }
    }

    public int CurrentImage
    {

        get
        {
            return currentImage;
        }
        set
        {
            currentImage = value;
        }
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return ImageCount;
        }
        set
        {
            ImageCount = value;
        }
    }

    public List<string> URLS
    {
        get
        {
            return UrlList;
        }
        set
        {
            UrlList = value;
        }
    }
```